# List all tags that don't have an excerpt?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, data-explorer

I saw this [SQL query on another question](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix%20and%20linux/query/81002/all-tags-by-frequency?opt.textResults=true), but I didn't know about the members in the table. How can I list all the tags created that have no excerpt yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just check [`ExcerptPostId`](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix%20and%20linux/query/81635/all-tags-without-a-wiki-excerpt)

On a sidenote, if you're looking for this so you can start adding lots of excerpts, can you be a little more careful? It's helpful that you suggest wiki edits, but your wikis are generally only a sentence or two and still manage to have typos at least half the time. For example, this question you just wrote is a single sentence and manages to have [multiple problems](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1034/revisions)

Comment: Looks better with a link, and sorted by count: http://data.stackexchange.com/unix%20and%20linux/query/81670/all-tags-without-a-wiki-excerpt

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll use a spell checker. And I will not add wiki for obvious tags like `keyboard`.

Comment: Shouldn't excerpt be precise? How long should it be then

Comment: @warl0ck It's not the length, it's the number of errors. If it's a language barrier problem then that's fine; I can't tell. But it'd save work for the people reviewing the edits if you proofread them

Comment: @MichaelMrozek okay, will do