# Can you polish up the chrome tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Calling all those interested in helping the site and potentially gaining a [tag editor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/badges/53/tag-editor) or [research assistant](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/badges/108/research-assistant) badge!

We have a tag with an old, copy-pasted excerpt & wiki that could use some attention:

- [chrome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome) - https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/chrome/info

If you follow this tag or know enough about its use on this site, please consider taking some time to improve its excerpt and/or wiki!

Two resources that I've relied on are:

- [Redesigned Tags Page](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/)
- [Examples of great tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120586/examples-of-great-tag-wikis)

### The guidelines that I use for myself

A *good* excerpt will:

- define the shared quality of questions containing this tag -- boiled down to a few short sentences
- Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized
- Concentrate on what a tag means to your community
- Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag. In other words, what kinds of questions should have this tag + common alternatives (“don’t use this tag”)

An *awesome* wiki will expand on the excerpt, plus have a clear structure, such as:

About [tag]:

- fuller description (wikipedia?), with key features
- logo & link to any official website
- list of alternative implementations and related (client/server access) programs

Using [tag] in Unix.SE:

- other release/version-specific versions of the tag, if any
- tags that get confused with this one (“what this tag is *not* about”) -- see the History tag for an example; also “mac” vs “mac address”

Additional resources:

- in-line text of common troubleshooting tips (top 1 or 2 Q’s?)
- links to Q’s for common tasks, FAQ’s, canonical / popular Q’s
- guide to any In-program help
- links to any online communities / forums
- links to good/popular books, guides, articles

---

PS. These are the top 3 tags (question-wise) from [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/721119/janitortags-excerpt-wiki).

Comment: Linking: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2968/psa-if-you-are-not-going-to-spend-any-effort-writing-an-useful-tag-wiki-excerpt

Comment: Linking: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/353/117549

Comment: Linking: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/554/117549

Comment: Linking: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1034/117549

Comment: Of course, this raises the question of whether [tag:boot] incorporates [tag:bootloader].

Comment: Great question; my initial assumption didn't meet the boot tag description. I'd suggest we fix one of my mistakes with this question and open a separate thread to discuss boot-related tags.

Comment: Bah! I started writing the tag wiki for [tag:boot-loader] at the weekend and while researching related tags, I noticed that there is a fair amount of overlap with [tag:boot]. Anyhow, I've submitted my work for peer review.

Comment: I've split [autocomplete out to a separate question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4618/can-you-improve-the-autocomplete-tag) to keep this question from dragging out. I'll create a separate boot/bootloader Q if/when I can get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve just updated the excerpt (usage guidance) and tag wiki for [chrome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome).  I was going to update the boot-loader tag but working on the Chrome tag took a lot longer than I had anticipated.

I've now also completed the usage guidance and a first draft of the tag wiki for [boot-loader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boot-loader).