# "You ... you complete me" said the autocomplete tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Calling all those interested in helping the site and potentially gaining a [tag editor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/badges/53/tag-editor) or [research assistant](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/badges/108/research-assistant) badge!

We have a tag with an old, copy-pasted excerpt & wiki that could use some attention:

- [autocomplete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autocomplete) - https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/autocomplete/info

If you follow this tag or know enough about its use on this site, please consider taking some time to improve its excerpt and/or wiki!

### To avoid duplicate effort

Please comment on this post if you intend to update the excerpt or wiki, so that we do not end up with wasted effort. Consider the comment an advisory lock. If you don't feel like making a full edit/contribution, consider adding an Answer here with suggestions on the direction you'd like to see the excerpt or wiki take.

Two resources that I've relied on for tag excerpts & wikis are:

- [Redesigned Tags Page](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/)
- [Examples of great tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120586/examples-of-great-tag-wikis)

### The guidelines that I use for myself

A *good* excerpt will:

- define the shared quality of questions containing this tag -- boiled down to a few short sentences
- Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized
- Concentrate on what a tag means to your community
- Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag. In other words, what kinds of questions should have this tag + common alternatives (“don’t use this tag”)

An *awesome* wiki will expand on the excerpt, plus have a clear structure, such as:

About [tag]:

- fuller description (wikipedia?), with key features
- logo & link to any official website
- list of alternative implementations and related (client/server access) programs

Using [tag] in Unix.SE:

- other release/version-specific versions of the tag, if any
- tags that get confused with this one (“what this tag is *not* about”) -- see the History tag for an example; also “mac” vs “mac address”

Additional resources:

- in-line text of common troubleshooting tips (top 1 or 2 Q’s?)
- links to Q’s for common tasks, FAQ’s, canonical / popular Q’s
- guide to any In-program help
- links to any online communities / forums
- links to good/popular books, guides, articles

---

PS. I discovered this tag from [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/721119/janitortags-excerpt-wiki).